# ReloadTableView with new NSMutableArray

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios4

I am using customTableView.I want to reload my tableViewCell with new data from my NSMutableArray.How can i do that?Here is my current Code for the tableView :

tableView.m

```
//
//  GameTableView.m
//
//  Created by Mahmudul hasan on 4/6/11.
//  Copyright 2011 JU. All rights reserved.
//

#import "GameTableView.h"
#import "BeginingCell.h"


@implementation GameTableView

@synthesize XmlManipulatorObject,QuestionMutableArray,dictionary;
@synthesize _tableView=tableView;


#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Table view data source


-(void)viewDidLoad
{

    [super viewDidLoad];

    XmlManipulatorObject=[[xmlManipulator alloc] init];
    QuestionMutableArray=[[XmlManipulatorObject ReadXml] retain];

    dictionary=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    dictionary = [QuestionMutableArray objectAtIndex:0];

}


-(IBAction) goBack:(id) sender{

    [self.parentViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

}


-(void) btnAction:(id) sender {
    NSString *str = ((UIButton*)sender).titleLabel.text;
    UIAlertView *alrt=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:str message:str 
                                               delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:nil ];

    [dictionary removeAllObjects];
    [alrt show];
    [alrt release];

    if(dictionary==nil)
    {
        NSLog(@"dictionary is nill now");
    }

    else {
        NSLog(@"dictionary is not nil");
    }



}



//Method to iterate trough a NSMutableDictionaries in a NSMutableArray

-(NSMutableArray*)GetQuestionByKey:(NSInteger *)key :(NSMutableArray *)Array
{
    NSMutableArray *arr;
   for (dictionary in Array) {

       if (dictionary!=nil) {
           arr=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
            [arr addObject:[dictionary objectForKey:@"option1"]];   

       }
   }

    return arr;
}



- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}


// Customize the number of rows in the table view.
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return 1;
}



- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {


    NSLog(@"%@",[dictionary objectForKey:@"question"]);
    NSLog(@"%@",[dictionary objectForKey:@"option1"]);
    NSLog(@"%@",[dictionary objectForKey:@"option2"]);
    NSLog(@"%@",[dictionary objectForKey:@"option3"]);
    NSLog(@"%@",[dictionary objectForKey:@"option4"]);

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"BeginingCell";

    BeginingCell *cell=(BeginingCell *)[_tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];


    if (cell == nil) {

        NSArray *topLevelObjects=[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"BeginingCell" owner:self options:nil ];

        for(id CurrentObject in topLevelObjects)
        {
            if ([CurrentObject isKindOfClass:[BeginingCell class]]) {

                cell=(BeginingCell *) CurrentObject;
                cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;


                break;
            }
        }

    }


    // Configure the cell.




    if(indexPath.row==0)
    {
        cell.myImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"man_kirstie_alley.jpg"];
        cell.SectionTitle.text=[dictionary objectForKey:@"question"];
        cell.Option1.text=[dictionary objectForKey:@"option1"];
        cell.Option2.text=[dictionary objectForKey:@"option2"];
        cell.Option3.text=[dictionary objectForKey:@"option3"];
        cell.Option4.text=[dictionary objectForKey:@"option4"];


        ///For showing the option idntity
        [cell.button1 setTitle:@"A." forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [cell.button2 setTitle:@"B." forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [cell.button3 setTitle:@"C." forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [cell.button4 setTitle:@"D." forState:UIControlStateNormal];


        ///For selecting the correct answer
        [cell.ansBtn1 setTitle:@"A" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [cell.ansBtn2 setTitle:@"B" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [cell.ansBtn3 setTitle:@"C" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [cell.ansBtn4 setTitle:@"D" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

        [cell.ansBtn1 addTarget:self action:@selector(btnAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [cell.ansBtn4 addTarget:self action:@selector(goBack:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    }


    return cell;

}



-(void)viewDidUnload
{
    [self dealloc];

}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

call

```
[tblView reloadData];
```

when you are updating your mutable array.

Comment: -(void) btnAction:(id) sender {
 
 
 
    NSString *str = ((UIButton*)sender).titleLabel.text;
    UIAlertView *alrt=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:str message:str 
              delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:nil ];
 
 //[dictionary removeAllObjects];
 //[alrt show];
    //[alrt release];
 
 dictionary = [QuestionMutableArray objectAtIndex:1];
 
 NSLog(@"%@",[dictionary objectForKey:@"question"]);
 
 [_tableView reloadData];
 
 if(dictionary==nil)
 {
  NSLog(@"dictionary is nill now");
 }
 
 else {
  NSLog(@"dictionary is not nil");
 }



} i tried with this

Comment: i am loading my dictionary with new data.but the tableView is not reloading accordingly.

Comment: set a breakpoint inside " if(indexPath.row==00" and check if the execution come here.

Comment: HOW CAN I CALL IT IN BUTTON ACTION?

Comment: set a break on [tblview reloadData] and let me know its coming there

Comment: it's crashing over the [tbl reloadData]..with error : “EXC_BAD_ACCESS”.

Comment: dictionary=[QuestionMutableArray objectAtIndex:1]; 
[tableView reloadData]; It's executing the [tableView reload] but i am not getting changes in the tableView.